# Fundamental theorem of calculus for $f(x) = \int_a^x g(t,x) dt$

Tags: calculus

The fundamental theorem of calculus states
\begin{align}
f(x) = \int_a^x g(t) dt \quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{df}{dx} = g(x)
\end{align}
What if $f(x) = \int_a^x g(t,x) dt$, then does the fundamental theorem of calculus still holds? I think in this case this should be changed but confused with proper notations(?) or expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not the same. What you are looking for here is the Leibniz rule for integration:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)dt = f(x,b(x))\frac{db}{dx} - f(x,a(x))\frac{da}{dx} + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)dt
$$
you can read more about assumed conditions etc here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule.

---

Interestingly, in the case that ${a(x)}$ and ${b(x)}$ are constant, you get the nice special case
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{b}f(x,t)dt = \int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)dt
$$
which can be very helpful for solving integrals. I think it was Feynman that said it was his favourite method of solving integrals, and so it's often referred to as "Feynman's trick".